# Modal href does not work set inside AJAX request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, modal-dialog

I have an AJAX Request on timer (every 5 seconds):

```
function getAvisierung(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'content/ajax.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { get_item: 'get_avis', page: 'Advice'},
    success: function(data){
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      $("#avis_content").html('');
      for(var x=0; x<obj.length; x++){
        $("#avis_content").append('<a href="#" data-original-title="Test" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a><a class="modal-basic delete_item" href="#deleteAvis" data-id="id" data-original-title="Löschen" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

But then `href` does not work for my modal dialog and tooltip. Any ideas why?

When I use just the HTML - it works. When it is in an AJAX request - it does not.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX

```
 $('[data-toggle="ajaxModal"]').on('click',
          function(e) {
            $('#ajaxModal').remove();
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this)
              , $remote = $this.data('remote') || $this.attr('href')
              , $modal = $('<div class="modal" id="ajaxModal"><div class="modal-body"></div></div>');
            $('body').append($modal);
            $modal.modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
            $modal.load($remote);
          }
        );
```

HTML

```
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;  </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Another button...</a>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
 </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Comment: THIS IS TOTALLY COPY and PASTE from https://jsfiddle.net/9b5vmwbv/1/. Learn how to come up with your own answer or at least say where you copied the code from